# General pointers to take care when implementing aggregations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database-performance

I have noticed the obvious slight performance slowness on MongoDB when I implement aggregations especially more complicated once such as the ones with multiple levels of aggregations or aggregations with bucketing etc.

However, are there certain things that I should follow/ensure to maintain or improve the performance of MongoDB aggregation queries?

Comment: Here are couple of documents you can refer to: [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) _and_ [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using [cursor.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) to see various stats.

It will help you to know what mongodb did to get you the output.

For understanding the output of `cursor.explain()` please read through these docs.

[Query Planner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#queryplanner)

[Execution Stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats)

Once you understand how your query is working behind the scenes, first thing you can start with would be indexes.

See if you have indexes on your collection.

If yes, is your query using the indexes to get the output. (You can find this by `explain()` command)

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc [Query Optimisation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/), some of the things to follow are:

> 1. Create Indexes to Support Read Operations

Use [db.collection.explain("executionStats")](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain) methods to provide statistics about the performance of a query. These statistics can be useful in measuring if and how a query uses an index.

Refer: [Pipeline operators and indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-expressions)

> 2. Early Filtering: Make the query more selective by filtering out documents in a collection

When possible, place $match operators at the beginning of the pipeline.

> 3. Evaluate Performance of Current Operations

For more information, see [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) and [Analyze Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/).

> 4. Use Projections to Return Only Necessary Data

When you need only a subset of fields from documents, you can achieve better performance by returning only the fields you need

Additional tips:

- Use of `$unwind` for large arrays causes the overall set to use a lot of memory and slows things down.The other alternative that you can do with MongoDB 2.6 and greater is `$filter` the array content before you `$unwind` it
- Date string comparisons are heavy, So its better to store the dates as MongoDB date object and do all the comparisons with date type itself instead of date string type.